# What's the difference between additive, semi-additive, and non-additive measures

Tags: data-warehouse, business-intelligence

I have searched in the net what's the difference between additive, semi-additive, and non-additive measures in a data warehouse. I have found some results but I have difficulty understanding the differences because they aren't an example. Could you please explain to me more the difference between additive, semi-additive, and non-additive measures with examples.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

> The numeric measures in a fact table fall into three categories. The most ﬂexible and useful facts are fully additive; additive measures can be summed across any of the dimensions associated with the fact table.

An example of a fully additive measure is sales (purchases from a store).  You can add hourly sales to get the sales for a day, week, month, quarter, or year.  You can add sales across stores or regions.

> Semi-additive measures can be summed across some dimensions, but not all; checking account or savings account balance amounts are common semi-additive facts.

You can recreate a balance amount from the transactions file, but it doesn't make any sense to add the balance amounts from October, November, and December (across the time dimension).

> Finally, some measures are completely non-additive, such as ratios. A good approach for non-additive facts is, where possible, to store the fully additive components of the non-additive measure and sum these components into the ﬁnal answer set.

Finally, you calculate the ﬁnal non-additive fact.

Emphasizing that, usually, non-additives are averages and percentages and ratios and it is irrelevant to perform additional aggregations on them (for example summing 2 selling ratio of a product will not be meaningful at all), 
Thus non-additive facts should not be stored within the fact table and will usually be manipulation on the additive facts within the fact table.

---

**Source:**
[[1]](http://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-techniques/dimensional-modeling-techniques/additive-semi-additive-non-additive-fact/)

Comment: Thanks Sir your answer is very helpful